# How to count the number of different between two set of vector from binomial distribution?

Tags: r, count

I want to count how many difference between `x` and `y` where `x` and `y` from binomial distribution. I have done the code but I would like to have another easier or more simplified code instead of the code below, not sure whether it is possible or not.

```
x <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.7)
y <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.4)

z <- 0
for (i in 1:20){
  if (x[i]!=y[i]){
    z <- z+1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sum(x != y)
```

This boolean expression is vectorized across x and y.